# Utilizar Certificado Digital sem estar instalado no computador

Tags: certificado-digital, instalador, assinatura-digital

Queria saber se existe alguma maneira de utilizar certificados digitais em uma aplicação sem a necessidade do certificado digital estar instalado na máquina.
Como na emissão de Nota Fiscal, sempre utilizo os certificados instalados na máquina. Tem alguma maneira de gravar o arquivo no Banco de Dados ou em outro local, para ser usado de qualquer outra máquina ou dispositivo?
Ja vi alguns sistemas utilizarem dessa maneira, podendo assim emitir Notas Fiscais pelo celular ou de qualquer outro computador.
Poderiam me dar alguma dica por onde começar ou onde procurar?

Comment: `Tem alguma maneira de gravar o arquivo no Banco de Dados ou em outro local` tem sim é só exportar ele para um arquivo e use a mídia que desejar para levar para outra maquina ou dispositivo

Comment: a dica vai de brinde http://www.seginfo.com.br/gerando-certificados-digitais-auto-assinados-com-openssl/

Comment: Eu uso certificados A1 gravados num armazenamento específico da aplicação. Basta as suas funções de SSL e assinatura buscarem num stream seu, e não no OS. Fica a sugestão de, ao fazer isso, proteger devidamente o certificado e não gravar a chave privada em aberto, senão você prejudica a segurança do cliente. (na verdade tem como fazer isso o A3 também, mas aí o "buraco é mais embaixo") –

Comment: @Bacco teria algum exemplo de como faz o armazenamento?

Comment: @henriqueromao o armazenamento pode ser feito em DB, arquivo, etc, depende só como é que vc vai usar. No meu caso, eu guardo num DB mesmo. O único cuidado é criptografar antes. Ao fazer uso, a senha do usuário é usada para abrir a chave e decriptar. Não usei a própria senha de usuário, pois mais de um pode ser autorizado a usar o certificado. Nesse caso, uma cópia da chave é encriptada individualmente com cada senha e id.